# Assigning Numbers to Playing Cards

Tags: c#, loops

I am doing exercise from C# tutorial and I need to print each card from the standard deck of 52 cards.
I have this code:

```
for (int n = 2; n <= 14; n++)
{
    for (int c = 1; c <= 4; c++)
        Console.Write(n + " " + c + " ");
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

But I am stuck and not sure how to substitute numbers with representing them suits and ranks.
I'm supposed to use loops and switch statements.

Comment: Just FYI, a deck of cards contains 52 cards - 4 sets of 13

Comment: yes, thats why 2-14 represent cards and 1-4 their sets

Comment: he has that, he's just treating aces as high

Comment: I believe he was referring to the question body "...from the standard deck of 53 cards"

Comment: Did you attempt this on your own? Your loops are correct, and you were given the information to use a switch statement. Googling "c# switch statement" provides https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx which will give you exactly what you are looking for

Comment: yes, the code is mine. I'm familiar with switch statements. So I should write  case for each card

Comment: Personally I would do it how juharr or Christos did it, but if you want to use a switch statement as per your stated requirements from the tutorial, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using loops and switch statements. You can make a variation of this for nicer card and suit names.

```
for (int n = 2; n <= 14; n++)
{
    for (int c = 1; c <= 4; c++)
    {
        switch (n)
        {
            case 11:
                Console.Write("J" + " ");
                break;
            case 12:
                Console.Write("Q" + " ");
                break;
            case 13:
                Console.Write("K" + " ");
                break;
            case 14:
                Console.Write("A" + " ");
                break;
            default:
                Console.Write(n.ToString() + " ");
                break;
        }
        switch (c)
        {
            case 1:
                Console.WriteLine("H");
                break;
            case 2:
                Console.WriteLine("D");
                break;
            case 3:
                Console.WriteLine("S");
                break;
            case 4:
                Console.WriteLine("C");
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("?");
                break;
        }

    }

}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution! That's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

You could declare two enumerations one for the suits and one for the ranks and just loop through them.

```
public enum Suits { Hearts, Spades, Clubs, Diamonds }

public enum Ranks 
{ 
    Ace, 
    Two, 
    Three, 
    Four, 
    Five, 
    Six, 
    Seven, 
    Eight, 
    Nine, 
    Ten,  
    Jack, 
    Queen, 
    King 
}
```

Comment: in accordance to tutorial I'm suppose to use loops and switch statements

Comment: @paddy Then you really should include that in your question.

Comment: @paddy You can still loop through an `enum`, just use `foreach(Ranks rank in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Ranks)))`

Answer (score 3):

You could create two string arrays and just `foreach` over both.

```
var suites = new [] { "Clubs", "Spades", "Hearts", "Diamonds" };
var ranks = new [] { "Deuce", "Three",...., "Ace"}

foreach(var suite in suites)
    foreach(var rank in ranks)
        Console.WriteLine(rank + " of " + suite);
```